# Why is `$(git branch)` outputting all files' names inside folder (besides git branches)?

Tags: command-line, bash, git

I wrote a command to delete all git branches without needing to write them all mannually, which is currently like this:

```bash
git branch -d $(git branch)
```

It does what I want, but also tries to delete branches named as files in current directory, so the output is something like this:

```shell
error: branch 'angular.json' not found.
error: branch 'assembly.xml' not found.
error: branch 'ci-settings.xml' not found.
error: branch 'coverage' not found.
error: branch 'cypress.json' not found.
error: branch 'Dockerfile.angular' not found.
error: branch 'Dockerfile.spring' not found.
error: branch 'e2e' not found.
error: branch 'examples' not found.
error: branch 'mvnw' not found.
error: branch 'mvnw.cmd' not found.
error: branch 'nginx' not found.
error: branch 'node' not found.
error: branch 'node_modules' not found.
error: branch 'package.json' not found.
error: branch 'package-lock.json' not found.
error: branch 'pom.xml' not found.
error: branch 'README.md' not found.
error: branch 'scripts' not found.
error: branch 'serve-proxy.conf.json' not found.
error: branch 'src' not found.
error: branch 'target' not found.
error: branch 'to-do.txt' not found.
error: branch 'tsconfig.json' not found.
error: branch 'web.config' not found.
error: Cannot delete branch 'dev' checked out at 'D:/Documentos/oreons/Rise/archivekeeper-ui'
Deleted branch test (was 729628a).
```

If I echo `$(git branch)`, the output is like this:

```shell
$ echo $(git branch)
angular.json assembly.xml ci-settings.xml coverage cypress.json Dockerfile.angular Dockerfile.spring e2e examples mvnw mvnw.cmd nginx node node_modules package.json package-lock.json pom.xml README.md scripts serve-proxy.conf.json src target to-do.txt tsconfig.json web.config dev
```

Which explains the command's output. But why does `$(git branch)` outputs all these file names besides the git branches?

Comment: IIRC `git branch` marks the current branch with an asterisk - the unquoted expansion `$(git branch)` will then be subject to filename generation (globbing), turning the `*` into a list of non-hidden filenames in the current directory

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) mentions in the above [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449606/why-is-git-branch-outputting-all-files-names-inside-folder-besides-git-br#comment2530817_1449606), `git branch` has an asterisk (`*`) in its output to mark the currently checked-out branch.

```bash
$ git branch
* main
  test
```

When running it as `$(git branch)`, that asterisk in the output is expanded to all non-hidden files and directories in the directory you're currently in.

To remove the asterisk, you can format the output by passing the `--format` option by only showing the short format of the refnames.

```bash
$ git branch --format='%(refname:short)'
main
test
```

So the command you want to use would be the following.

```bash
git branch -d $(git branch --format='%(refname:short)')
```

Comment: Mind blown! Good explanation.

Comment: And the moral is - always examine the output of a command _first_ before using it as input to something else, especially something destructive

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `git branch` in scripts. Instead, use the low-level commands such as [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref):

```
git for-each-ref --shell --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | \
while read branch; do git branch -d "$branch"; done
```

or

```
git for-each-ref --shell --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | \
xargs git branch -d
```

This avoids the problem of the command from the question, because it correctly quotes parameter expansions. Not quoting a parameter expansion (or command substitution) will perform *pathname expansion* on the expanded value.

Since `git branch` is a user-facing command, it marks the current branch with a `*`. And as you might know, `*` as a globbing character/wildcard, which resolves to any 0 or more characters. When executing `echo *`, your shell first expands and replaces `*` with all (non-hidden) files in your current directory, then passes this list of files as parameters to `echo`.

Conclusion: *always* quote "dollar-expressions" (not a real term, I am talking about *parameter expansions* and *command substitutions*) to prevent field splitting and pathname expansion – unless you have very good reasons to not do so (and know what you are doing)

Comment: Downvoted as this does not answer the OP's question of *why* they're getting the behavior they're seeing.

Comment: This is a more robust solution than the currently accepted one, I think

Comment: @jwodder I disagree with the downvote. `git branch` internally uses `git for-each-ref`, and `for-each-ref` is better and safer to use in scripts. My answer directly answers OP's question, but this answer is more correct as a "permanent" solution.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know I could prevent this expansion with surrounding the expression with double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in a shell function for essentially the same purpose, though it leaves `main`, `master`, and the current branch (marked with the asterisk as discussed in the older answer and comment).  You may find it useful.

```sh
git branch |
    grep -v '^\*' |
    grep -oE '[^ ]+' |
    grep -vE '^(master|main)$' |
    while read branch_name; do
        git branch -D $branch_name
    done
```

Comment: Downvoted as this does not answer the OP's question of *why* they're getting the behavior they're seeing.

Comment: That was already answered in perfect detail.  I'm not going to repeat that uselessly, I'm going to help OP further.